# How long does it take for a published content type in the Gallery to become available across your environment?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

How long does it take for a published content type in the Gallery to become available across your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will vary based on the number of tenants on the stamp and number of content types across the tenants in the stamp. I.e. if there are 5 tenants and each has 10 CTs in the hub, it'll be super quick. If there are 500 tenants with 1000 CTs in the hub each, it's going to take a lot longer.

And for both scenarios, there will be variances depending on farm load.

There is no SLA around the timer job that executes this process.

Microsoft is putting forth effort to improve performance of CT hub publishing, though.

Ultimately, giving you a number will be anecdotal and inaccurate.